# Can I call "getNodeInfo" via UDP the same way I can call it over TCP?

Tags: iota-network, udp, tcp

I've noticed a lot of nodes with connection_type UDP vs TCP. Are the UDP ones running the same IRI 1.4.1.4 api?

Specifically, I'm trying to write to a network connection:

`conn.Write([]byte("{\"command\": \"getNodeInfo\"}"))`

I'm not getting anything back. However, "getNodeInfo" over HTTP TCP work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three different protocols and ports involved when running a node:

- HTTP control / API port (default `tcp 14265`)
- TCP neighbor port (default `tcp 15600`)
- UDP neighbor port (default `udp 14600`)

The neighbor ports are only used to transfer transactions between neighbors. That's why you are not getting anything back, the UDP port simply doesn't support the API commands.

The HTTP control / API port is the actual interface that supports such commands but (by default) is not accessible from public.

Comment: Is HTTP not running via port 80?

Comment: @Helmar HTTP can run on any port you choose, it's just that IRI (the node software) doesn't have a default port specified for that.